# Get sum of field values within distance with simple features (sf)

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I'm trying to get the sum of values from a field on a sf object for all points within a given distance to each point, excluding the value of the point.

```
set.seed(123);m=matrix(runif(30,1,40),ncol=3)
loc<-m %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c(1,2))
a<-st_is_within_distance(loc,dist=10)
> a
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 10, where the predicate was `is_within_distance'
 1: 1, 6, 10
 2: 2, 4
 3: 3
 4: 2, 4
 5: 5, 8
 6: 1, 6
 7: 7, 9
 8: 5, 8
 9: 7, 9
 10: 1, 10
```

How can we get a data frame with a list of those 10 points with the sum of V3?

```
    point|sum
    1    | sum_of_v3_of(6,10)
    2    | sum_of_v3_of(4)
...
```

This is fairly easy to do with postgis but have all the other code in R and would like to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do the following:

```
data.frame(point = 1:length(a), sum = sapply(a, function(p) sum(loc$V3[p])) - loc$V3)
#    point      sum
# 1      1 35.37012
# 2      2 39.77652
# 3      3  0.00000
# 4      4 28.01933
# 5      5 24.17154
# 6      6 35.69203
# 7      7 12.27723
# 8      8 26.57253
# 9      9 22.21857
# 10    10 35.69203
```

It becomes easy once we notice that `a` is a list (see `str(a)`) with elements, e.g., 1, 6, 10 in as its first element, `a[[1]]`, and that `loc` also is a list with an element `V3` that can be reached by `loc$V3`. So, then using `sapply` we go over the elements of `a`, look at the corresponding elements of `loc$V3` and sum them up. As a result `sapply` returns a vector and we are left with creating a data frame or a matrix for the results.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Exactly that! (just had to subtract the value of the point itself but worked great)